# Setting write permissions on Django Log files

Tags: django, apache, chmod

I have a set of Django Log files, for which I have the appropriate logger set to write out messages. However each time it creates a new log file, the permissions on the file don't allow me to start the shell, and at times cause issues with apache.

I have ran chmod -Rv 777 on the directory, which sets all the permissions so we can do what we like, but the next logfile created, goes back to some default.

How can I set permissions on the logfiles to be created

Marc

Answer (score 4):

Permissions on files created by a particular user depend on what mask is set for this particular user.

Now you need to set the appropriate permissions for whoever is running the apache service

```
ps -aux | grep apache | awk '{ print $1 }'
```

Then for this particular user running apache (www-data?)

```
sudo chown -R your_user:user_running_apache directory
```

where *directory* is the root directory of your django application.
To make sure that all the files that will be added to this directory in the future have
the correct permissions run:

```
sudo chmod -R g+s directory
```

Comment: what if i am using nginx ?

Answer (score 2):

I faced with the same problem - I had issues with starting shell and with celery due to rotated-log file permissions. I'm running my django-project through the uwsgi (which is running by www-data user) - so I handled it by setting umask for it  (http://uwsgi-docs.readthedocs.org/en/latest/Options.html#umask).

Also I'm using buildout, so my fix looks like this:

```
[uwsgi]
recipe = buildout.recipe.uwsgi
xml-socket = /tmp/uwsgi.sock
xml-master = True
xml-chmod-socket = 664
xml-umask = 0002
xml-workers = 3
xml-env = ...
xml-wsgi-file = ...
```

After this log file permissions became 664, so group members of www-data group can also write into it.